# Error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I want to select a subset of a data.frame containing only information about the current date.

```
today = Sys.Date()
LasttDate = paste("'",today,"'",sep = "")
> LastDate
[1] "'2013-04-30'"
```

The selection is performed via the following code containing the date and it works

```
Lastdbdata = dbdata[dbdata$DateNav == '2013-04-30',]
```

In case we do not want to write all the times the Date but we want it to be selected automatically when running the code I though we could write instead

```
    Lastdbdata = dbdata[dbdata$DateNav == LastDate,]
    Errore in charToDate(x) : 
    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

but it does not work and returns the error above.
Which is the trick to solve this error?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting that error because `DateNav` is in `Date` format already, while `Lastdate` is not. Comparing `DateNav` to `today` should do the trick:

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2013-04-30"
> Sys.Date()==as.Date("2013-04-30")
[1] TRUE
> Sys.Date()==as.Date("'2013-04-30'")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

In fact, even if `DateNav` were not in `Date` format, you could/should compare directly with `today`.

```
> Sys.Date()=="2013-04-30"
[1] TRUE
```

I am not sure what the rationale is for inserting single quotes. If you want to convert the date to character for some other reason, there's always

```
> as(Sys.Date(),"character")
[1] "2013-04-30"
```