# Checking if date is blank in R?

Tags: r, date, testing

An easy one but I am sure someone knows how to do this...

In R, I was looking for something like *is.blank* to error trap in my function where a User can specify a date **or it can be blank** and we will default to use Today's date (i.e. `Sys.Date()`)

I tried

```
date.end <- ""

# then in function  
if (date.end == "" || is.null(date.end)) {
  message("end date not specified and so setting to today")
  date.end <- Sys.Date()
} else {
  # use the date.end passed in as Date class
}
```

But this check freaks out charToDate(), i.e.

```
test.end == ""
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Please advise **how does one check for blank dates in base R?**
(And any other wisdom for error trapping dates...)

*Adding to clarify:*

1. Most times the function will get good dates, e.g.

   ```
   date.end <-  as.Date("31/03/2015", "%d/%m/%Y")
   ```

   So I do not want to change class.
2. However, how do you handle the odd case where you want to default to today if user does not specify a date?

Comment: Try `nchar(test.end)==0` in your test

Comment: `nzchar` would be analogous to your request for `is.blank` but like @Tim Biegeleisen mentions, I would convert the vector to dates and test for NA; this would tell you not only which are blank but which do not follow your specified format

Comment: Thanks @csgillespie. I was worried that nchar(NULL) == 0 gives length issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that `Sys.Date()` returns an object of the `Date` class. See `class(Sys.Date())`. Hence the `==` comparison does not make sense as you are comparing a `character` with a `Date`.

One way to solve your problem is to convert the `Date` to a `character`:

```
date.end <- ""

# then in function  
if (date.end == "" || is.null(date.end)) {
  message("end date not specified and so setting to today")
  date.end = as.character(Sys.Date())
}
##end date not specified and so setting to today

date.end == ""
##[1] FALSE

print(date.end)
##[1] "2015-04-01"
```

Note that `date.end` is now a `character`.

Please see the discussion in [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297731/error-in-chartodatex)

**EDIT:** Complete overhaul. OK, from reading your follow-up comments and questions it appears that you want something like the following (although it's still not quite clear).

I think you're making this more complicated than it is. First, let's make a function that can handle a *single* (i) `Date`, (ii) a perhaps ill-formatted `character`, or (iii) the `NULL` object.

```
dateHandler <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x) || identical(x, "")) {
    out <- Sys.Date()
  } else {
    x <- as.character(x)
    out <- as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    if (is.na(out)) {
      out <- Sys.Date()
    }
  }
  return(out)
}

# Let's test it in a number of examples:
dateHandler("2014-02-21")
dateHandler(NULL)
dateHandler("21/03/1999") # Wrong format, returns today
dateHandler("")
dateHandler("2014-04-01")
dateHandler(Sys.Date())
```

Now, let's make a function that applies `dateHandler` on a list of dates:

```
handleListOfDates <- function(list.of.dates) {
  return(do.call(c, lapply(list.of.dates, dateHandler)))
}

# Let's test that:
test.data.list <- list("2014-05-01", NULL, "", Sys.Date(), 
                       "2015-02-02", "1999-12-31", "")
#print(test.data.list)  # See this

handleListOfDates(test.data.list)
# [1] "2014-05-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-02-02" "1999-12-31" "2015-04-01"
```

The function `handleListOfDates` will also correctly handle a `vector` instead of a `list` of dates.
Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Or I could stick with dates and force date to character before test? e.g. as.character(date.end) == "". This could work!

Comment: PS I think you meant "Note that..." not Not

Comment: @micstr Yes. That's what I would do. Forcing dates with e.g. with `as.Date` would yield `NA`s. You would then do something like Tim suggests.

Comment: It seems is.null does not work on a vector. e.g. mylist <- list(date.end.blank, date.end.null, date.end.ok),  is.null(mylist) returns just TRUE,  not FALSE TRUE FALSE if I wanted to use it for indexing

Comment: @micstr First, `is.null` tests if the given object is the `NULL` object. `is.null(list(Sys.Date(), NULL, ""))` returns `FALSE` (and not `TRUE`) as expected because this is a `list` which is obviously not the `NULL` object. It does not work on each element of the `list`. Also, a `vector` is not the same as a `list`.

Comment: Thanks @AEBilgrau that is **genius**.  I appreciate your effort and I learnt a lot. a) I see now NULL is more like a condition of an object that a NaN/error value b) I agree I am making it too complex. I am trying to work out how to error trap, but covering all bases is a tricky c) `as.character` then reapplying `as.Date` is brilliant with the `na` catch!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NA` for the missing dates, and then replace those `NA`s with the default value:

```
date.end[is.na(date.end)] <- Sys.Date()
```

Comment: Thanks @tim-biegeleisen. I was relying on user leaving end date blank if he wanted to default to today. I cannot be sure they will reliably enter NA, so I cannot accept your answer just yet.  I need a blank test

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use elements of people's answers. Like @tim-biegeleisen na idea as an index. And typing from @aebilgrau and @csgillepsie. `NULL` just causes troubles:

- trips up the pipe operator
- `is.null` returns one TRUE/FALSE so you cannot use it as an index, like `is.na`
- sapplying with is.null to get indexing Booleans gets upset with single values.

and so this gets convoluted!

```
library(data.table)

date.end.ok <- as.Date("31/03/2015", "%d/%m/%Y")
date.end.null <- NULL
date.end.blank <- ""

date.end.list <- list(date.end.blank, date.end.null, date.end.ok)
date.end.dt <- data.table("date"= date.end.list )


testdate <- function(date.end) {

  # checks
  # sort out any nulls first, replace with NA to not trip up |
  # note null has length 0
  if (length(date.end) <= 1) {
    end.date.is.null <- is.null(date.end)
   } else {
    # sapply will not work on null or single value
    # work along list (I am expecting input to be data.table column)
    end.date.is.null <- sapply(date.end, is.null)
  }
  date.end[end.date.is.null] <- NA #replace with NA to not trip up |

  end.date.is.bad <- (as.character(date.end) == "" |  
                      end.date.is.null) #Thanks aebilgrau

  # any problems found? any(end.date.is.bad) 
  if (any(end.date.is.bad)) {
    message("end date not specified and so setting to today")
    date.end[end.date.is.bad] <- as.Date(Sys.Date(),
                                     "%d/%m/%Y") #Thanks tim-biegeleisen
  } else {
     # go with date.end given    
  }

  #happy
  return(date.end)
}
```

This kinda works for lists and single values. Indexing ok. 
**But does not keep** the As.Date type! i.e. returning

- testdate(date.end.blank)  "16526"
- testdate(date.end.null) 16526

I think I might just close my eyes to being a type NULL in [r](/questions/tagged/r)

*I did not put this in my original answer as looked like too much detail.*

> Sorted: Please see **@aebilgrau** amended **datehandler** answer and +1 it!

Answer (score -1):

You set "end.date" <- "" and then you test for "date.end" but it fails.  Note how "end" and "date" are flipped in assignment and testing.

Otherwise, `end.date == ""` should work, or you can test for number of characters in the string `nchar(end.date)`, which would be zero in your case.

Comment: thanks for spotting that - will fix. It still gives that error though

Answer (score -1):

You can use something similar to this:

```
dplyr::mutate(Result = case_when(is.na.POSIXlt(DATE_var) ~ "<Alternative date_var or sys.date()>", TRUE ~  DATE_FINALIZADO))
```